# Expected primary expression before ';' token - new to c++

Tags: c++, calculator

So, I'm tasked with creating a simple calculator, that firstly will take 1 number, than the action you want to perform on it, and than the second number, problem is, I can't get it to work because (at least I think its because of that) the compiler can't take +, -, *, / as a char. what can I do to solve it?
allot of thanks in advance, I've tried to search a solution for a while now and couldn't...

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double first;
    double second;
    char x;
    char add  = "+" ;
    char take = "-" ;
    char add2 = "*" ;
    char take2 = "/";
    cout << "Please enter the first number\n";
    cin >> first;
    cout << "Please enter the math action\n";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Please enter the second number\n";
    cin >> second;
;    if (x == add)
    {
        cout << first << x << second << "=" << first+second;
    }
    if (x == take)
    {
        cout << first << x << second << "=" << first-second;
    }
    if (x == add2)
    {
        cout << first << x << second << "=" << first*second;
    }
    if (x == take2)
    {
        cout << first << x << second << "=" << first/second;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Couldn't reconize the character, please try again";
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, the `char` type can only contain a single character, while e.g. `"+"` is a pointer to an array of characters. You want `'+'` instead (note the difference between single (`'`) and double (`"`) quotes).

Comment: As for your error, *where* do you get the error? At what line in the shown code do you get the error?

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you should correct here.

1. Use `char c = 'x';` instead of `char c = "x";` to set a character: double quotes give you a string, and single quotes give you a character.
2. There's a stray semicolon at the beginning of one of the lines half way through.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this ; first from

```
;    if (x == add)
```

and use single qoute '  while assigning char instead of "